# Javascript Function And PHP Code On Resizing Image On Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a javascript way of uploading an image. Now I have my codes below showing the function upload image, I need this function to resize or allow to me to set image size to be save into database.

```
function upload_image()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["image1"])) 
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['image1']['name']);
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
        $destination = 'machine_images/' . $new_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $new_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: **I need this function to resize or allow to to set image size to be save into database.** You want first or second one ?

Comment: To resize an image, sir @ Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: No one is sir here

Comment: The first one sir @ Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: I mean no one is sir in the field of technology. Neither you nor me :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143562/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-techgirl).

Answer (score 0):

To resize image, you can use php `imagecopyresized` function.

`imagecopyresized` — Copy and resize part of an image.

Ex:

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)